# HTML5 Canvas - Changing a square into a circle

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

On an HTML5 canvas I can't find a method to make colored circles. I've been consulting [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp) as a reference.

Here is my current attempt

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = "cornerRadius";
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

(Also on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvnm21r1/1/)

I've tried using the canvas `arc` method, which creates a circle, but doesn't color it.

I can't use the `border-radius` property, because `ctx` is not an element.

Is there any way, I can transform my squares into circles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want your square to turn into a circle after some time? Or do you just want a circle?

Comment: I'd just like a circle. That's what I've been trying to create

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JSfiddle with a circle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvnm21r1/5/)

To draw a circle you'll need to draw an arc and have a starting angle and an ending angle. So you'll have to use Pi and define a radius.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
```

Comment: An important point, to color a circle set the `context.fillStyle` before you call `fill()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use quadratic curves to "round-out" the straight lines of your square until they form a circle.

[image][image][image]

```js
// change sideCount to the # of poly sides desired
//
var sideCount = 4;


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = randomColor();

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 100;

var xx = function (a) {
  return (cx + radius * Math.cos(a));
}
var yy = function (a) {
  return (cy + radius * Math.sin(a));
}
var lerp = function (a, b, x) {
  return (a + x * (b - a));
}

var sides = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sideCount; i++) {
  sides.push(makeSide(i, sideCount));
}

var percent = 0;
var percentDirection = 0.50;

$("#toShape").click(function () {
  percentDirection = -0.50;
})

$("#toCircle").click(function () {
  percentDirection = 0.50;
})

animate();

// functions

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  drawSides(percent);
  percent += percentDirection;
  if (percent > 100) {
    percent = 100;
  }
  if (percent < 0) {
    percent = 0;
  }
}

function drawSides(pct, color) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (pct == 100) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(sides[0].x0, sides[0].y0);
    for (var i = 0; i < sideCount; i++) {
      var side = sides[i];
      var cpx = lerp(side.midX, side.cpX, pct / 100);
      var cpy = lerp(side.midY, side.cpY, pct / 100);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, side.x2, side.y2);
    }
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function makeSide(n, sideCount) {
  var sweep = PI2 / sideCount;
  var sAngle = sweep * (n - 1);
  var eAngle = sweep * n;

  var x0 = xx(sAngle);
  var y0 = yy(sAngle);
  var x1 = xx((eAngle + sAngle) / 2);
  var y1 = yy((eAngle + sAngle) / 2);
  var x2 = xx(eAngle);
  var y2 = yy(eAngle);

  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;
  var a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  var midX = lerp(x0, x2, 0.50);
  var midY = lerp(y0, y2, 0.50);
  var cpX = 2 * x1 - x0 / 2 - x2 / 2;
  var cpY = 2 * y1 - y0 / 2 - y2 / 2;

  return ({
    x0: x0,
    y0: y0,
    x2: x2,
    y2: y2,
    midX: midX,
    midY: midY,
    cpX: cpX,
    cpY: cpY,
    color: randomColor()
  });
}

function randomColor() {
  return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toShape">Animate to Shape</button>
<button id="toCircle">Animate to Circle</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, that's fancy. First answer that answered the literal question: *"Is there any way, I can transform my squares into circles?"* Although I have the feeling the OP just wanted to figure out hot to draw a circle.

Comment: I suspect the same thing...I just had to do the animation though ;-)  Notice that the very last bit of the animation does indeed use the arc command (because qCurves can't create a perfect circle). So both requests are technically filled :-)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid w3schools.com whenever possible. Refer to sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) instead.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
var radius = 50; // Arc radius
var startAngle = 0; // Starting point on circle
var endAngle = Math.PI*2; // End point on circle
ctx.arc(150, 75, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: *"I've tried using the canvas arc method, which creates a circle, but doesn't color it."*. - You should mention how to color a circle. This does not add anything the OP didn't do.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - `ctx.fill();` fills the circle (thought that was obvious from the code).

Comment: Read my comment again, I don't see you at all mentioning how to **color** a circle. To do so you need to set the `fillStyle` to a certain color. It's black by default.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - So what's wrong with black? And the OP's issue was the inability to create a circle in the first place, stroked or filled. Picking a color is a secondary issue. Plus, the MDN link I provided goes into greater detail.

Comment: The OP asked twice how to create a **colored circle**, and mentioned **they can create a circle, but it's not colored**. They obviously need to call `fill()` (or `stoke()`) to even draw the circle on the screen. It's possible the OP can already do this exactly.